# SSIS 2016 Visual Basic Component Runtime Failure: "The system cannot find the file specified. IBM.Data.Informix.4.0.410.02

Tags: vb.net, ssis, ado.net, informix

I'm struggling to find any meaningful information on this issue so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

I have a SSIS 2016 package that has a Visual Basic Script Component that requires connectivity to a remote Informix database via an ADO.Net connection. The necessary project reference to the IBM.Data.Informix.dll has been added and the project builds without error. However when the package executes a runtime  failure occurs:

**"Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.Informix.4.0.410.02, Version=4.0.410.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"IBM.Data.Informix.4.0.410.02, Version=4.0.410.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208"**

I have tried some of the suggested solutions I have come across including setting the reference property, "Copy Local = False" as well as repointing the reference to the various versions of the installed dll. File locations include the GAC, "C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client SDK\bin..." and  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM Informix Client SDK\bin...". Both 32 and 64 bit versions are installed and the dll files do exist in the referenced locations. All attempted solutions failed.

Any suggestions where I can go to from here?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Try manually adding the two .NET providers to your GAC.   Find  a suitable "gacutil.exe" tool (usually shipped with the .NET SDK) doing a simple "dir C:\gacutil.exe /s"  for 32/64 GACs and then register the provider with "gacutil /I D:\infx\csdk410tc10\bin\netf40\IBM.Data.Informix.dll" (using your CSDK directory).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go however it will take a few days; I don't have permission to modify the GAC so  it'll have to be passed to another team.